# Check if numpy's array_like is an empty array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose `a` is an `array_like` and we want to check if it is empty. Two possible ways to accomplish this are:

```py
if not a:
   pass

if numpy.array(a).size == 0:
   pass
```

The first solution would also evaluate to `True` if `a=None`. However I would like to only check for an empty `array_like`.

The second solution seems good enough for that. I was just wondering if there is a numpy built-in function for that or a better solution then to check for the size?

Comment: You definitely should not use the expression `not a`. If `a` is, in fact, a numpy array with size 0, in recent versions of numpy that expression will generate a deprecation warning: *DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.*  And that messages suggests that checking the `size` attribute is the recommended method.

Comment: Also note that if `a` is a list such as `a = [[], [], []]`, then `not a` will be False (because `len(a)` is 3), but `np.array(a).size` is 0 (because the array that is created has shape (3, 0)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if size is zero, you might use `numpy.size` function to get more concise code

```
import numpy
a = []
b = [1,2]
c = [[1,2],[3,4]]
print(numpy.size(a) == 0)  # True
print(numpy.size(b) == 0)  # False
print(numpy.size(c) == 0)  # False
```